# Magento 2 : php 7.4 not work for install 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

I want to install Magento 2.4.3 on my subdomain
I set the subdomain php version to 7.4
But this error is shown

Magento supports PHP 7.3.0 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements.

Comment: seems to me like you are not running php 7.4 but maybe php7.2, can you show outpu of 
 phpinfo()

Comment: @roman204 I use phpinfo() and show 7.4.24

Comment: magento 2.4.3 is installed using the console. the console and server can use different versions of php. try using command php7.4 bin/magento setup:install ...

Comment: @Vitalii i use php selector for this problem and this problem resolved but this error show This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies